# Multilinear or Tensor Regression?

Tags: statistics, regression, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Given input data $x_t\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and output data $y_t\in\mathbb{R}^m$, the closed form solution to $\min_A \sum_t \|y_t - Ax_t\|^2_2$ is given by $A = (XX^T)^{-1}XY^T$ where $x_t$ form the columns of $X$ and similarly for $Y$. This is the solution to least-squares regression.

Suppose instead of one set of inputs, we had $k$ sets of inputs $x^1_t,\ldots,x^k_t$ from vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^{n_1},\ldots,\mathbb{R}^{n_k}$ and we wanted to find the *multilinear* map $A$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n_1}\times\ldots\times\mathbb{R}^{n_k}$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ that minimizes

$$\sum_t \|y_t - A(x^1_t,\ldots,x^k_t)\|^2_2$$

Is there a closed form solution to this? Trying the usual method (write out multilinear map in index notation, take derivatives and set to zero) it looks like

$$A = \sum_t y_t \otimes (X^1X^{1T})^{-1}x^1_t \otimes \ldots \otimes (X^kX^{kT})^{-1}x^k_t$$

might work, where $\otimes$ denotes outer product, but my algebra could be wrong. It does, at least, reduce to the least squares regression case when $k=1$.

Comment: I must have misunderstood.. But why can you not just stack all the x's side by side so that your X matrix has (n1 + .. + nk) columns and repeat? Is it just a question on notation?

Comment: No - there is the difference between a linear map (a matrix) and a multilinear map (a higher-rank tensor), which is a kind of nonlinear map.